# How to preserve input values in search/filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have just managed to get the filter function on my index action working.
So now you can use:

```
myurl.com/questions?status=approved&description=blahblah
```

I am using the index view where I have added a simple form

```
<%= form_tag questions_path, :method => :get do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :description %>
    <%= select_tag :status, options_for_select(question_statuses), :include_blank => true %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
<% end %>
```

However, when the page is re-displayed with the filter applied the input field and the select tag obviously doesn't contain the values from the last request. How do I manage to preserve the values?

I thought of making instance variables in the controllers action and use them in the view for accessing the params[:status] and params[:description], but I don't know if this is a "hairy" solution? Or do you just use params straight in the view?

*Current solution is params[:attribute] in the view.*

Comment: Try [ransack](https://github.com/ernie/ransack/). It's more heavy, but it will make your code much cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

You should set value, for example like this:

```
text_field_tag :description, params[:description]
```